# Select a MYSQL result where tables one and two match and two and three do not match

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

I have a two tables with users in an old format and a new format. I want to match the users with the old format to a separate table, then exclude all users who also show up in the new user format table. My data is like this:

```
Table newUsers:
+----+-------+-------+----------+
| id | oldid | first | last     |
+----+-------+-------+----------+
|  1 |    10 | John  | Kennedy  |
|  2 |    66 | Mitch | Kupchak  |
+----+-------+-------+----------+

Table posts:
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |      10 |
|  1 |      66 |
|  1 |      88 | 
|  2 |      88 | 
|  2 |      28 | 
|  3 |      10 | 
+----+---------+

Table oldUsers:
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| id | username | first | last     |
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 10 |        A | John  | Kennedy  |
| 66 |        B | Mitch | Kupchak  |
| 88 |        C | Dale  | Earnhardt|
+----+----------+-------+----------+

Result wantend:
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| id | username | first | last     |
+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 88 |        C | Dale  | Earnhardt|
+----+----------+-------+----------+
```

I want to select my result by specifying: posts.id = 1 and posts.user_id = oldUsers.id and newUsers.oldid != oldUsers.id so that I only receive oldUser.id equaling 88 because he wasn't in the newUsers list.

I have tried all kinds of JOINS and SUBQUERIES. I keep getting all of the results and not the results minus corresponding entries in the newUsers table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
select 
o.* from oldUsers o 
left join newUsers n on o.id = n.oldid 
left join posts p on  n.oldid = p.user_id or o.id = p.user_id 
where n.id is null and p.id= 1;
```

For better performance add the following indexes

```
alter table newUsers add index oldid_idx(oldid);
alter table posts add index user_post_idx (id,user_id);
```

Comment: This worked, but took 3.5 seconds and when doing explain it said it created a ton of rows with the first left join. So it is too inefficient to use.

Comment: You need indexes into the table, I have added the indexes you may need for the tables. I am assuming the ids from both olduser and newuser are primary key so no need to apply extra index on them.

Comment: Added them and it did bring it down to .023 on average. But my own code still executes 5.22 times faster.

Comment: Remeber you are doing implicit join between `post` and `olduser` so yes inner joins are better than outer join. I added outer join in case of some missing data from some table will be picked up. However its always better to use inner join if there is scope to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from oldusers where id in

select * from

(select id from oldusers where id in
 select distinct userid from posts where id=1) 
 where id not in (select oldid from newusers);
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual  that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from

(select id from oldusers where id in
 select disti' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer on my own and then came here to find others tried. Abhik's code did work, but was too inefficient to use. I ended up playing with my own code and IS NULL until I found something that was much more efficient.

```
select o.* from posts p, oldUsers o 
LEFT JOIN newUsers n ON o.id = n.oldid 
WHERE p.user_id = o.id AND p.id = 1 AND n.id IS NULL
```

Executes in .0044 seconds. Something I can use on a production site.

With indexes added from previous answer it now executes in .001x seconds so definately going with my own code.